# extending a class with namespace in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload, extends

I'm trying to write my first framework with namespaces.
I've got a problem with extending class Controller.
I get

> Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in xxx/src/controllers/index.php on line 3

A Controller looks that:

```
namespace src\libs;
class Controller 
{}
```

And here is my Index class in `src/controllers/`

```
namespace src\controllers;
use src\libs as libs;
class Index extends libs\Controller
{}
```

My autoload:

```
function autoLoader($class)
{
    $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);
    if (file_exists('./' . $class . '.php')) {
        require( './' . $class . '.php');
    } else {
        $class = explode('/', $class);
        if (file_exists( LIBS . end($class) . '.php')) { 
            require( LIBS . end($class) . '.php');
        } else {
            echo 'Critical error!!';
            exit;
        }
    }   
}
```

> LIBS = ./src/libs/

AutLoader works, because it includes file with class Controller, I don't get error. I have not idea why it isn't work.

Comment: What is the location of your `Controller` ?

Comment: src/libs/Controller.php

Comment: I hope this will help you in debugging your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine for me

**File:** `/var/www/html/PHP/Randoms/src/libs/Controller.php`

```
<?php
namespace src\libs;
class Controller 
{

}
```

**File:** `/var/www/html/PHP/Randoms/src/controllers/Index.php`

```
namespace src\controllers;
use src\libs as libs;
spl_autoload_register(function($classname){
    $classPath=str_replace("\\", "/", $classname);
    $filePath= dirname(__FILE__)."/../../".$classPath.".php";
    if(file_exists($filePath))
    {
        require_once $filePath;
    }
});
class Index extends libs\Controller
{}
```

Comment: Now it is working, because i had a bugs in Bootstrap. I am beginner in namespace ;)